# Why gets the R ShinyServer running slower?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have running some shiny apps on Shiny Server version 1.5.3.838 - libc6 (2 2.7) r-base (2 2.15.1) and R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) and Ubuntu version 16.04.7 LTS.

Last time the server is extremely slow. Now and than I do:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart shiny-server
```

then the apps are running faster, but after a while they run slow again.

Is there any solution for this? Or is there a strategy to follow in order to find the cause of this?

Comment: Is it just the applications that are running slowly or the server itself? Do other things have the same issue? Are the apps being used while this is occurring?

Comment: Thanks, good questions, I will find out.